# margin auto with and without scroll bar in chrome and firefox not the same

Tags: css, iframe, scrollbar

I read some question before but could not find out the answer solved this problem at all. I have to area one of this contain an iframe and other display player to play music. I'm using margin auto and It's work fine but not for scroll bar vertical.
I am trying to always display scroll bar but in some case the content short enough to not display scroll bar.
I'm trying javascript solution:

```
var w =     window.innerWidth;
if(!w){
    w = document.documentElement.offsetWidth; // for IE
}
var outsize = parseInt(Math.round((w-1000)/2));
$("#body-content").css({'margin':'0 '+outsize+'px'});
$("#player",parent.document).css({'margin':'0 '+outsize+'px'});
```

get the width of the window and re-margin the content and the player. But at the first time It's slightly move few pixels. It's look very ugly.
Anyone here have the difference solution for this, pls help me!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. If I understand your question correctly, you can use `overflow-y: scroll`. This will show the vertical scroll bar at all times.

Comment: Tks my Head Hurts, but my player must not have scroll bar and some page like login page could not display full screen so display scroll in this situation so ugly

Comment: Sorry, I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi there, Can you please show your code or real time example so we can identify what exactly you want to achieve. For ex: you can put your sample code in jsfiddle.net or upload your image/screen-shot so we can see. It will be useful for any one to understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

does the following added to your css file help?

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

it should always display the scrollbar, greyed out if the content is smaller than the screen and active when the page gets higher.